# How to use less ressource when add new custom CSS or blog post?

Tags: wordpress

Hello for my website [Fameways](https://fameways.com) when i add new CSS or add new blog post the server getting slow during few minutes maybe 5/10 minutes and then the website is fast. It's like ON/OFF button server... Anyone know how to fix this ? i already disable autosave blog post wordpress, add wp-rocket and more but it's not fixing it.

Thanks fo your answer

Disable autosave wordpress
Add wp-rocket
Disable heartbeat API wordpress
Disable all plugins not necessary on new blog post editor

Comment: Please read ["Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/215552) as well as [ask] and [edit] your post.

Comment: I think its because WPRocket need to precharge again all pages and make new Cache, even just for a small change but how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solve, for anyone have same issue at my end it was because WP CRON send too much request so need to disable and also increase memory limit.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).